# Regarding increase in MSE of Cross-Validation model with increasing dataset for regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have the following experimental setup for a regression problem.

Using the following routine, a data set of about 1800 entries is separated into three groups, validation, test, and training.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inputs, targets, test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=42, shuffle=True)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25,
                                                  random_state=42, shuffle=True)
```

So in essence, training size ~ 1100, validation and test size ~ 350, and each subset is then having unique set of data points, that which is not seen in the other subsets.

With these subsets, I can preform a fitting using any number of the regression models available from scikit-learn, using the following routine:

```
model = LinearRegression()
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), model)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Doing this I then calculate the RMSE of the predictions, which in the case of the linear regressor, is about ~ 0.948.

Now, I could instead use cross-validation and not worry about splitting the data instead, using the following routine:

```
model = LinearRegression()
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), model)
predictions2 = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42))
```

However, when I calculate the RMSE of these predictions, it is about ~2.4! To compare, I tried using a similar routine, but switched X for X_train, and y for y_train, i.e.,

```
model = LinearRegression()
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), model)
predictions3 = cross_val_predict(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42))
```

and received a RMSE of about ~ 0.956.

I really do not understand why that when using the entire data set, the RMSE for the cross-validation is so much higher, and that the predictions are terrible in comparison to that with reduced data set.

### Additional Notes

Additionally, I have tried out running the above routine, this time using the reduced subset `X_val, y_val` as inputs for the cross validation, and still receive small RMSE. Additionally, when I simply fit a model on the reduced subset `X_val, y_val`, and then make predictions on `X_train, y_train`, the RMSE is still better (lower) than that of the cross-validation RMSE!

This does not only happen for LinearRegressor, but also for RandomForrestRegressor, and others. I have additionally tried to change the random state in the splitting, as well as completely shuffling the data around before handing it to the `train_test_split`, but still, the same outcome occurs.

### Edit 1.)

I tested out this on a `make_regression` data set from scikit and did not get the same results, but rather all the RMSE are small and similar. My guess is that is has to do with *my* data set.
If anyone could help me out in understanding this, I would greatly appreciate it.

### Edit 2.)

Hi thank you (@desertnaut) for the suggestions, the solution was actually quite easy, and the fact was that in my routine to process the data, I was using `(targets, inputs) = (X, y)`, which is really wrong. I swapped that with `(targets, inputs) = (y, X)`, and now the RMSE is about the same as the other profiles. I made a histogram profile of the data and found that problem. Thanks! I'll save the question for about 1 hour, then delete it.

Comment: Please do not double-intend your code snippets; either use reverse quotes or indent the code - don't do both (edited).

Comment: Difficult to say more without the data, and the fact that you cannot reproduce the issue with `make_regression` indicates that the issue is there indeed. We can offer only speculations (and SO is not the place for doing so). Advice: spend some serious time exploring your data; it maybe the case that there are some (possibly huge) outliers than end up in your val subset and cause mayhem. Also, try the same experiments with different random seeds (imposing different data splits) - does the behavior persist?

Answer (score 0):

You're overfitting.

Imagine you had 10 data points and 10 parameters, then RMSE would be zero because the model could perfectly fit the data, now increase the data points to 100 and the RMSE will increase (assuming there is some variance in the data you are adding of course) because your model is not perfectly fitting the data anymore.

RMSE being low (or R-squared high) more often than not doesn't mean jack, you need to consider the standard errors of your parameter estimates . . .  If you are just increasing the number of parameters (or conversely, in your case, decreasing the number of observations) you are just chewing away your degrees of freedom.

I'd wager that your standard error estimates for the X model's parameter estimates are smaller than your standard error estimates in the X_train model, even though RMSE is "lower" in the X_train model.

Edit: I'll add that your dataset exhibits high multicollinearity.

Comment: Hm it was even simpler than that! But thank you, I will look more into using standard errors of estimates. They seem about normal now (see above edit). There is high multi collinearity in the data set, yes.

Comment: Sweet, yeah that's an issue.  If that mistake wasn't made the multicollinearity exhibited by your model would've been VERY high.